Oracle regexp_replace
I’m currently stuck on the regexp_replace to make a working pattern for updating thousands of rows…
Strings will look like this:
nvl(replace('$$TAG1$$$$TAG2$$$$TAG3$$' …) … $$TAG4$$ = '12345678' … INSTR('product1, product2,',',$$TAG5$$,') … GET_CODE($$TAG6$$, 'something')

I modified string a bit, but key parts stay the same.
I need to replace (add quote encasing) only to those $$TAG$$ which are not in quotes yet. Those would be &&TAG6&& and $$TAG4$$
Current pattern:
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
    q'{nvl(replace('$$TAG1$$$$TAG2$$$$TAG3$$' …) … $$TAG4$$ = '12345678' … INSTR('product1, product2,',',$$TAG5$$,') … GET_CODE($$TAG6$$, 'something')}',
    q'{(\'\${2}.*\${4}.*\${2}\')|(',\${2}[A-Za-z0-9_/i]+\${2},')|(\${2}[A-Za-z0-9_]+?\${2})}',
    q'{\1\2'\3'}'
) AS result
FROM dual;

Result:
nvl(replace('$$TAG1$$$$TAG2$$$$TAG3$$''' …) … '$$TAG4$$' = '12345678' … INSTR('product1, product2,',',$$TAG5$$,''') … GET_CODE('$$TAG6$$', 'something')

As you can see, after TAG3, and TAG5, appears two additional quotes..
Please help:)

Does your string really contain curly quotes? Or is that an artefact of the editor you are using and they are really straight quotes?


Split the string into tokens using a row-generator;
Get a running count of the quotes;
If a tag is not inside a quote then surround it by quotes; and
Aggregate the string.

Like this:
SELECT s.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LISTAGG(
                  CASE
                  WHEN term LIKE '$$%$$'
                  AND  MOD(num_quotes,2) = 0
                  THEN '''' || term || ''''
                  ELSE term
                  END,
                  NULL
                ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pos) AS value
         FROM   (
           SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.value, q'!'|\$\$.*?\$\$|(\$?[^'$]+)+!', 1, LEVEL) AS term,
                  COUNT(
                    CASE
                    WHEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.value, q'!'|\$\$.*?\$\$|(\$?[^'$]+)+!', 1, LEVEL) = ''''
                    THEN 1
                    END
                  ) OVER (ORDER BY LEVEL) AS num_quotes,
                  LEVEL AS pos
           FROM   DUAL
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(t.value, q'!'|\$\$.*?\$\$|(\$?[^'$]+)+!')
         )
       ) s;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
  SELECT q'{nvl(replace('$$TAG1$$$$TAG2$$$$TAG3$$' ...) ... $$TAG4$$ = '12345678' ... INSTR('product1, product2,',',$$TAG5$$,') ... GET_CODE($$TAG6$$, 'something')}' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



VALUE




nvl(replace('$$TAG1$$$$TAG2$$$$TAG3$$' ...) ... '$$TAG4$$' = '12345678' ... INSTR('product1, product2,',',$$TAG5$$,') ... GET_CODE('$$TAG6$$', 'something')



fiddle

Works wonders. Thank you very much!
